# Prevent deletion if relationship exist - Fluent API

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, ef-fluent-api

There's a `One to Many` relationship between Catergory and Product. One catergory will have many products. However, when I try to delete a catergory, and if there's a product with that catergory I shouldn't be allowed to do so.

In the code I wrote it allows deletion. When I delete a Catergory it also deletes the associated product.
What I want my code to do is, to do is to prevent me from deleting a Catergory if there are corresponding records.

Can someone help me sort this out.

Catergory

```
public class Catergory
{
    public int CatergoryId { get; set; }
    public string CatergoryName { get; set; }
    public string CatergoryDescription { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }

}
```

Product

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string ProductDescription { get; set; }
    public int CatergoryID { get; set; }

    public Catergory Catergory { get; set; }
}
```

Using Fluent API to map relationships

CatergoryConfiguration

```
class CatergoryConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Catergory>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Catergory> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Catergory");

        builder.HasKey(c => c.CatergoryId);

        builder.Property(c => c.CatergoryName)
            .IsRequired(true)
            .HasMaxLength(400);

        builder.Property(c => c.CatergoryDescription)
            .IsRequired(true);

    }
}
```

ProductConfig

```
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Product> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Product");

        builder.HasKey(p => p.ProductID);

        builder.Property(p => p.ProductName)
            .HasMaxLength(400)
            .IsRequired(true);

        builder.Property(p => p.ProductDescription)
            .HasMaxLength(2000)
            .IsRequired(true);

        builder.HasOne(f => f.Catergory)
            .WithMany(r => r.Products)
            .HasForeignKey(f => f.CatergoryID);
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot configure this in FluentAPI.
`OnDelete` only set the behaviour of how to handle related entities when a principal entity is deleted.

In your Delete Method you need to include logic to check if a `Category` has `Products` before deleting.